# Does such a function exist given the inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Im currently trying to find a nonzero function $h(x)$ in span $\{1,x,x^2\}$ such that $\langle h,1\rangle = 0$ and $\langle h,x\rangle = 0$ where the inner product is defined by $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)~dx$ but I'm having trouble coming up with one.

Does such an example exist?

---

**My work:** i put coefficients $a,b,c$ in front of the spanned terms and evaluated the two conditions. I'm left with $a + b/2 + c/3 = 0$ and $a/2 + b/3 + c/4 = 0$. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: What have you tried??

Comment: i put coefficients a,b,c in front of the spanned terms and evaluated the two conditions. I'm left with a + b/2 + c/3 = 0 and a/2 + b/3 + c/4 = 0. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You have almost solved it completely! Why couldn't you proceed further? Do you expect a unique triple $(a,b,c)$ and stopped because you could not generate another equation? In fact there are infinitely many quadratic polynomials that solve our question. We just need to find one of them (not zero).

Comment: i actually set a + b/2 + c/3 = a/2 + b/3 + c/4 and plugged in values for a and b to get c, but my result didn't work.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer, consider accepting it by clicking the tick-mark button next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $h=k_1+k_2x+k_3x^2$, then you have$$\begin{align*}\int_0^1(k_1+k_2x+k_3x^2)\cdot1~dx=0&\iff k_1+k_2/2+k_3/3=0\\\int_0^1(k_1+k_2x+k_3x^2)\cdot x~dx=0&\iff k_1/2+k_2/3+k_3/4=0\end{align*}$$We can solve for $k_i$ as follows:$$k_1=-k_2/2-k_3/3=-2k_2/3-k_3/2\implies k_2+k_3=0$$Thus we get $k_1=-k_2/6,k_3=-k_2$. We may select any value for $k_2$, say $k_2=1,k_3=-1,k_1=-1/6$. In fact, the general quadratic that satisfies our requirement is a constant multiple of $(-1/6+x-x^2)$ as$$k_1+k_2x+k_3x^2=k_2(-1/6+x-x^2),k_2\in\Bbb R$$